# Android in Xamarin.Forms can't compile after changing target framework

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms application. I changed the Target Framework version of the Android project from 10.0 (Q) to 12.0 (S). After that, I get error

> "java.exe" exited with code 1.

I cannot find any solution that would work for me.

ADDED: OK, now I know it is Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl package that I need for Google Analytics that causes the error. But I don't know how to go around it...

Comment: Do you have any other information besides what you have posted? There have been many changes from Android 10 to Android 12, so this could stem from a lot of reasons.

Comment: Do you also need to update the Xamarin library?

Comment: @tomerpacific I added packages Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics and Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics.Impl. Not sure what else it can be...

Comment: @quilkin I just updated Xamarin.Forms, and it did not help.

Comment: OK, probably no help but I gave up with c# / Xamarin a couple of years ago - every time VS or Android had a new version, I would get masses of errors to sort out. I switched to Java / Android Studio ,and had much better results ever since.

Comment: you need to look at the build log for relevant messages

Comment: @Jason What messages are relevant? I don't see any, but I may be missing it...

Comment: messages mentioning build errors.  You may need to turn up the verbosity of the build log.  Sometimes it takes some digging

Comment: @Jason But the problem is that there is only one build error: ...\Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(79,5): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.

Comment: What's your vs version? try to update it to the latest version.

Comment: @Adrain Zhu -MSFT It is the latest version 17.1.6. I don't know if this matters, but I also have a warning:  Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b0....
    "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b0..." was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b0..." was not.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have googled, and can't find anything useful...

Comment: (Don't worry about the CSharp warning.) So much has changed in the past two years, that your best bet might be to **start a new project** - to be sure all the basics are up-to-date, then start adding your sources and settings to it. Either it will "just work", or you'll isolate what causes the java.exe, and then someone can help. PITA, but it will get you there. An **alternative approach** is to clone your entire solution, then delete/comment out almost all of it. If you can find any subset that works, then you can build back until it breaks.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve OK, now I know it is Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl package that I need for Google Analytics that causes the error. But I don't know how to go around it...

Comment: you can try the solution in here https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/379

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Yes, I have seen this. I removed that package, and now I am trying to see if Google Analytics GA4 will work without it.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT After removing Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl the issue is gone, and AG4 works. If you make this your answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have same issue, try to check the version of your package or remove the Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl like this one did.